# Get actual email message from Spring Integration Mail-Receiving Channel Adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How can I extract the actual email Message from `org.springframework.messaging.Message` ?

Here is my actual code.

Configuration:

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter
    id="customAdapter" 
    store-uri="imaps://username:password@host/INBOX"
    channel="receiveChannel" 
    auto-startup="true" 
    should-delete-messages="false"
    should-mark-messages-as-read="false" 
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
/>

<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Java:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;

public class ImapTestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/config-imap.xml");

        DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);

        inputChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                // and now ?
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javax.mail.Message mailMessage = message.getPayload();
```

**EDIT**

Bear in mind that with your current code, the adapter will likely start before you subscribe the channel - it's best to subscribe something within the context. You could even use a `<service-activator/>` referencing a POJO method.

```
public void handle(javax.mail.Message message) {...}
```

and the framework will unwrap it for you.

If you want to keep your current code, you should set auto-startup to `false` and start the adapter after you subscribe to the channel.